# display articles based on their event date and not their publication date

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress:
Hello, I would like to display articles based on their date of event (eg seminar, internship, webinar ...) and not their date of publication. I can display articles based on their publication date, but not on their event. I specify that I have to do it with a shortcode and not from a plugin ... Thanks in advance for your help. I am a pure beginner in WP and PHP ...
Here is the code I tried:

```
function display_cpt($atts, $content) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'=> 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'page' => 'agenda'

    ), $atts);    
    $posts = get_posts($args);


    $html = '<ul>';   
    foreach($posts as $post) {        
        $html .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
    }    
    $html .= '</ul>';

    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('article_evenement', 'display_cpt');

?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well i cant found the event date? is it your custom field or something? please put that in your meta query 'orderby' => 'date', to 'orderby' => 'customfield',. Note this is rough  idea you have to find something from wordpress.org on meta query. If not found comment here, so i will help you.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide more info like if the event date is a meta box

Assuming that the event date is a custom meta_box or a custom_field your code should be like this:

```
function display_cpt($atts, $content) {
$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'page' => 'agenda'

), $atts);    
$posts = get_posts($args);


$html = '<ul>';   
foreach($posts as $post) {        
    $html .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
}    
$html .= '</ul>';

wp_reset_postdata();
return $html;
}

add_shortcode('article_evenement', 'display_cpt');

?>
```

Comment: Désolée, je n'ai pas l'habitude... effectivement, c'est une méta box... j'ai réussi à afficher mes posts mais ils sont toujours dans le désordre. Je sais qu'il faut utiliser orderby et un array avec ses particularités, je vais chercher sur la doc wordpress.  Et thanks a lot for your help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is finally what it took to display my articles according to the dates of the events. I put this code here if it can help someone in the future ... Thanks for your help, you have referred me well.

```
function display_cpt($atts) {
$atts = array(
    'numberposts' => 3, 
    'post_type' => 'cpt_agenda', // de la page custom post type agenda (que l'on retrouve dans l'url du back office)
    'meta_key'  => '_date_event', // travailler sur les dates d'évènements affichées _date_event dans le code et Date event dans le BO
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value', // ordonner par la valeur du champ _date_event (ici des dates)
    'order'     => 'ASC', 
    'meta_query' => array( 
        'relation' => 'AND', 
        array(
            'key' => '_date_event', // on souhaite comparer la clé de champ personnalisée _date_event
            'value'   => '', // et l'afficher si sa valeur est différente (compare !=) de vide (value '') 
            'compare' => '!=' // 
         ),                             // ET
        array(
            'key'     => '_old_event', // dont la valeur de l'évènement passé est égale à false, donc que notre évènement n'est pas
            'value'   => false, // encore passé.
            'compare' => '='  
        ),              
    ),
);   

$posts = get_posts($atts); 

$html = '<ul>';   
foreach($posts as $post) { 
    $html .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>'; 
}                                                                                    
$html .= '</ul>';

return $html;
```

}

add_shortcode('article_evenement', 'display_cpt');

?>